# How to simplify this list.append for lists within a list?

Tags: python, list, append

Hello I am trying to create a list called `wind_data_list` containing all the atmospheric data in sublists `(date, time, ws, d, t)`. I created the following code and it works fine. However, I would like to simplify the process of appending data, if possible by appending straight to the specific list (`date`, `time`, `ws`, `d`, `t`) in `wind_data_list` without appending first to the atmospheric data list and then the lists to `wind_data_list` (see code example). 
Hope it is clear.

Thanks in advance

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

prova = openpyxl.load_workbook('Prova.xlsx')
wind_data = prova['wind data']

#lists of data
wind_data_list = []

#atmospheric data list
date = []
time = []
ws = []
d = []
t = []

wind_data_list.append(date)
wind_data_list.append(time)
wind_data_list.append(ws)
wind_data_list.append(d)
wind_data_list.append(t)

#extract data from excel file "wind data"
for row in range (2, wind_data.max_row + 1):
    str_date_time = str(wind_data['A' + str(row)].value)
    wind_speed = wind_data['B' + str(row)].value
    direction = wind_data['C' + str(row)].value
    temperature = wind_data['D' + str(row)].value   

#processin data to be listed
    date_time = datetime.strptime(str_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date.append(str(date_time.year) + '/' + str(date_time.month) + '/' 
    +str(date_time.day))
    time.append(str(date_time.hour) + ':' + str(date_time.minute))
    ws.append(wind_speed)
    d.append(direction)
    t.append(temperature)


print(wind_data_list)    
print('done')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a dictionary, if it serves the purpose.

```
wind_data_list = {
    'date': [],
    'time': [],
    'ws': [],
    'd': [],
    't': []
}

wind_data_list['date'].append(date_data)
wind_data_list['time'].append(time_data)
wind_data_list['ws'].append(wind_speed_data)
wind_data_list['d'].append(direction)
wind_data_list['t'].append(temperature)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get element of main list and append to it directly.

```
wind_data_list[0].append(date_data)
wind_data_list[1].append(time_data)
wind_data_list[2].append(ws_data)
wind_data_list[3].append(d_data)
wind_data_list[4].append(d_data)
```